# Kafka Consumer Can handle millions of data ? Implementing kafka consumer in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Requirement:

Producer will push 5 millions/day of data to kafka Topic.
Topic has (105 partitions)

My job is
I need to consume all 5 millions data using spring-boot kafka consumer code
then next i need to convert to domain class and need to save into cosmos Db.

So here i have some question could anyone give answers.

1. how many consumesr do i need to use to consume 5 millision of data.
2. do i need to use auto commit true or do i need to acknowlege as soon as i consumed message.
3. please provide consumer configuration like poll time and message per poll.
4. if offset is not commiting how can i resolve.
5. howmuch data one partition can store.
6. if i want to implement manual acknowledge , how can i implment (any sample code)
   Could anyone help me on this

Comment: This would be a great learning and experience for you, also share with SO members. You can go ahead and tackle requirements 1 by 1. You can start with learning about kafka, its configuration

Comment: What types of messages are you trying to persist. Is this an event-driven architecture, or is this a message-triggered, ORM based service with a domain model/ aggregates that map to a service DB?